# Remove leafs from phytree if all the branches have same value

Tags: matlab, plot, tree, data-visualization, matlab-figure

I'm using MATLAB to generate 'phytrees' and I need to simplify them.

The way I thought is by removing subtrees where all the node has the same value and keep only this value + a number that represent how many nodes were deleted.

For example, here is one of the trees:

[image: ma]

and I want to replace the subtrees that have the same values like here:

[image: ma_zoom]

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What do you mean "the same value"? In all your images I can only see thigns with different values.

Comment: each mouse I have is from a certain strain , and the strains are in the left I did add them as yticklabel @Ander Biguri and I colored each strain by a chosen color

Comment: I am afraid that this will need a decent amount of coding, and you are not likely to get an answer, as there is no straightforward way of doing it in MATLAB. Good luck though.

Comment: @AnderBiguri it is OK I Know it would need some amount of code, if I know how to access the leaf nodes and their parent and children I can think of an algorithm to do it

Comment: What function do you use to create this tree? How does your data look like?

Comment: @EBH I use a dissimilarity matrix that was already generated using other program as an input (mouse to mouse dissimilarity matrex) 
and then using matlab seqneighjoin I create the phytree

and I have a table with 2 columns for mice, strains
this table I used to color and label the leafNodeLabels, and the YTickLabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a programmatic way to do it, but from the picture you attached I see that you use `plot` to view your figure. If instead, you'll use the [`phytreeviewer`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/phytreeviewer.html) (just type `view(your_phylotree)`) you'll get a different figure window, with other related tools.

Specifically, you'll see the **Collapse branch** button [image: Collapse], and the **Rename branch** button [image], which will together get you exactly what you want. The first "*removing subtrees*" (actually hiding them), and the second lets you change the branch name to "*value + a number*".

You can do all this also by simply right-clicking in the relevant brunch:

[image: right-click]

Here is an example with data from the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/seqneighjoin.html#btvnpuf-1):

```
% bulding some tree:
seqs = fastaread('pf00002.fa');
distances = seqpdist(seqs,'method','jukes-cantor','indels','pair');
phylotree = seqneighjoin(distances,'equivar',seqs);
view(phylotree)
```

After some collapsing and renaming on this tree, and printing it to a figure (with right click on the most top branch, or the root, that you want to include in the figure), I got:

[image: example tree]

Also, note that every time you hover with the mouse on a branch (even if collapsed) you get a list of the Leafs in that branch and their count:

[image: tooltip]

Comment: Thanx this really helped :)